# Remote Connection from the ssh2_exec to another remote and access to shell of new connection

Tags: php, shell, ssh2-exec

i Have already connected to a remote server using ssh2-connect , and i am using **ssh2**_exec to run this command `"sshpass -p 'xxxx1248' ssh XX@1x2.1xx.3x.xx "` , now if i connected to new remote server i want to access their shell.
i have a task to run command over there in second remote server.
how would i do ??

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($sIP, $iPort);

$autherised = ssh2_auth_password($connection, $sUserName, $sPassword);
$oResult = ssh2_exec($connection, "sshpass -p 'xxxx1248' ssh XX@1x2.1xx.3x.xx");
```

how to access the shell of IP `1x2.1xx.3x.xx`.

Please solve this if any one has done this before ....

Comment: Do you want to run a command on the target machine (1x2.1xx.3x.xx)?

Comment: Yes , i want to run few commands on target machine. and the first command will give me an ENV variable and using that variable i need to run another program which take 2-5 minutes to complete , will it work like i am doing ???

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a code snippet that will run the "ls" command on the target machine.  Let me know if this is what you want.

```
$conn = ssh2_connect($host, $port);
ssh2_auth_password($conn, $user, $pass);
// runs the ls -al command on $targetHost
$stream = ssh2_exec($conn,
    "sshpass -p '{$passTarget}' ssh $targetUser@$targetHost ls -al"
);

// retrieving the data
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$output = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);

echo stream_get_contents($output);
```

This code outputs the directory listing on the `$targetHost` machine.

I hope this helps.

Edit:

I will add an example here:

On my target machine, I created a small bash script, `test.sh`:

```
export TEST_VAR=1
```

Then I changed the `ssh2_exec` line to:

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($conn,
    "sshpass -p '{$passTarget}' ssh $targetUser@$targetHost 'source test.sh; echo \$TEST_VAR'"
);
```

I get the expected result: `1`

Comment: Thanks , Yes same thing I want but this ls , pwd these commands are working. but when I run any two commands is not work.
like I am running a sh program like this ,
`$stream = ssh2_exec($conn,
    "sshpass -p '{$passTarget}' ssh $targetUser@$targetHost 'source sequencerConfig.sh;echo $SEQUENCER_RUNS' "
);`
See , the sh program source to get the env variable $SEQUENCER_RUNS , which I am doing echo as second command. that output is an empty string.

Comment: Hello Amey, to be on the safe side, I set up a similar situation and everything works fine for me.  I believe that you did not escape `$` sign.  Try: `echo \$SEQUENCE_RUNS`.  I will edit my answer with a small example.